# CSS DIV tag padding that i need to get it off

Tags: css, html

I got problem with the css of my blog. The div or p tag has a off padding or something like that and the header which has 3 parts are very off by them self and i need the to get closer.

Can anyone help me?

Here is my site - `http://www.7naj.com/hl/wordpress`

Comment: Can you be more specific? You want the header doing what?

Comment: i want the gray part to go upward a little and also the green part to go up near the grey one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the reason your elements are so spread out is because of the images themselves - the negative space that you see is part of the image. There are 2 approaches that you can use to fix this:

**One:**

Edit the images to crop and remove the excess negative space (the unused white space that's pushing things away)

**Two:**

Apply a negative `margin` value to the necessary `<div>` or `<p>` elements accordingly. For example:

```
p {
 margin-bottom: -40px;
}
```

Comment: yeah that helped!!! thank you very much!
The second method helped :)

Comment: also do you know why the blue button and the green surface is no aligned with the other items from the table? thanks in advance!

Comment: @AleksandarCfcVelkov Yes. Change `vertical-align: baseline;` to `vertical-align: middle;` on your `<table>` and voila!

Comment: like this
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="vertical-align: middle;">

Comment: Also apply `vertical-align:middle;` to your td's as well.

Comment: i just did and it worked! Thank You Vinny you saved my life for today :) Thank You Very Much!

Comment: but now the link on ПОЧЕТНА button can not be clicked and i have not changed anything on it...